# Why isn't the verb separated in "Wenn du aufstehst"?

Tags: grammar, verb, separable-verb

I thought the translation for `What do you do when you get up?` would be:

> Was machst du, wenn du stehst auf?

But I've read it is:

> Was machst du, wenn du aufstehst?

Comment: Wieso sollte es?

Comment: Ist schon naheliegend, weil der entsprechende Hauptsatz _Du stehst auf_ lautet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to look at it the other way round:

The Verb actually is "[aufstehen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufstehen)".

The separation of the prefix in certain contexts happens because it's a "[**trennbares Verb**](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Trennbare-0n.html)" ([separable verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb)).
When used in a **main clause**, the prefix moves to the end of the clause. In a **dependent clause** it doesn't. Since what you have in your example is a dependent clause, the thing stays together.

Also related:

- [Wie kann man wissen, ob ein Verb trennbar ist?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/160/wie-kann-man-wissen-ob-ein-verb-trennbar-ist)
- [Conjunction of separable verbs?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/conjunction-of-separable-verbs)
- [Origin of Separable Verbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/origin-of-separable-verbs)

Answer (score 1):

The verb always comes at the end in a relative clause (*Nebensatz*).
*Wenn*, *weil*, *während*, *als* etc. usually signify the relative clause of a sentence.

> Was machst du, wenn du stehst auf?

is **wrong** as the verb *aufstehen* will be combined in a relative clause when conjugated form of *stehen* goes at the end.

Comment: The gist of the explanation is right, but note that inversion occurs in all subordinate clauses, not just relative clauses. In fact, none of your examples is a relative clause or a connector introducing a relative clause.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant subordinate clause, wrong words.